# Non-linear formulas in mgcv

Tags: nonlinear-regression, mgcv, brms

in brms (which is heavily based on mgcv) there is a possibility to define non-linear formulas (meaning not linear in parameters). However, for different reasons I need to use mgcv.

E.g. the model
`bf(y ~ b1 * exp(b2 * x), b1 ~ 1, b2 ~ 1, nl = TRUE)`
is not linear in its parameters.
Although for some easy examples there might be a possibility to rearrange the formulas such that they become linear in parameters, this does obviously not apply to more complex ones.

Is there something similar in mgcv such that the user can specify non-linear formulas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I suspect this is OT for [stats.se] as it isn't about a statistical question, instead being about software. I would expect this to be closed. It might be a better fit for [so].

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't; {mgcv} is not intended for fitting non-linear models of the form you show.

> (which is heavily based on mgcv)

{brms} isn't actually heavily based on {mgcv}, in fact most of the package uses code that has nothing to do with {mgcv}. The only thing {brms} uses from {mgcv} is the code needed to create the basis expansions for smooths, and the code used to convert these smooths into their respective random effect form.

The `nls()` function in base R and `nlme()` in the package of the same name can fit non-linear models.